# Blender 2.8 - Object index pass in Eevee

Tags: compositing-nodes, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I need to isolate filters on some objects in the compositor and Blender 2.8 does not have the options to setup object/material passes in the View Layers. Is there anyway to achieve this in Blender 2.8 and for EEVEE?

Comment: Blender 2.8 Cycles has Cryptomatte feature (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml1Kic4VopA) which is more versatile, so you do not need object/material pass index.

Comment: @3DSingh This is not my post though :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about unfinished experimental development software.

Comment: @3DSingh, cryptomatte is only available in cycles render, not Eevee.

Comment: For beginners seeing this post in future searches, I'll mention that 2.8 pass indices have been added back in as of now. But the whole thing is still of course a WIP and not ready for production.

Answer (score 3):

In 2.8, Cycles there is something called the cryptomatte node. Unfortunately, at the time of writing this, it is not implemented for Eevee.

I found a solution by creating view layers, then evaluating the depth in both. View layers are like 2.79's render layers, so you can exclude objects from being rendered in each.

Next, I evaluated depth in both view layers. Since one of the view layers is missing the object, you can use a greater than or lesser node to create a mask.

Here's a video on view layers: https://youtu.be/BBuD64KhxeY?t=1502

I imagine 2.8 Eevee will gain cryptomatte in the future.