# Portal effect in EEVEE?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, layers, collections

So I'm trying to make a portal effect for an animation, and unfortunately the only way i know of for doing this effect is by using layers and the compositor in 2.79, which were replaced with the collection system in 2.8:
[image: compositing node setup of two layers]

Is there a way of creating an effect similar to this with EEVEE's render engine?
[image: result of the "portal effect"]

Answer (score 6):

View and Render Layers are working similar to 2.79 but sadly EEVEE can't use Material/Object Index Pass. So you can't make a portal using this method. Read more here and watch video from the links: [Blender 2.8 - Object index pass in Eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121827/blender-2-8-object-index-pass-in-eevee)

### How to replicate it using different method

[image: final]

1. I've created two **Collections** - Portal and Behind_portal and also two **View Layers** accordingly.

   [image]
2. To exclude **Collection** from **View Layer** - select it and press <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>RMB</kbd> ***> View Layer > Set Exclude.***
3. In **Compositing** I've used **Color Key** to "remove" color of **Holdout** shader assigned to portal. I've also scaled a bit result and blurred it, as **Color Key** is not 100% precise.

   [image: comp]